# How to solve AWS Glue pyspark script throwing retryWrite error from DocumentDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

Running below code in AWS glue. Job is able to read the Data from DB but failing while writing.

An error occurred while calling o102.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Command failed with error 301: 'Retryable writes are not supported' on server :. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "code": 301, "errmsg": "Retryable writes are not supported", "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1647921685, "i": 1}}}

Used the catalogue DocumentDB connection in Job Details section

Tried using retryWrite=false in connection string but still getting the error

```
documentdb_uri = "mongodb://<host name>:27017"
documentdb_write_uri = "mongodb://<host name>:27017"

read_docdb_options = {
    "uri": documentdb_uri,
    "database": "test",
    "collection": "profiles",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "ssl": "true",
    "ssl.domain_match": "false"
}

write_documentdb_options = {
    "uri": documentdb_write_uri,
    "database": "test",
    "collection": "collection1",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "ssl": "true",
    "ssl.domain_match": "false"
}

# Get DynamicFrame from DocumentDB
dynamic_frame2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="documentdb",
                                                               connection_options=read_docdb_options)

# Write DynamicFrame to DocumentDB
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(dynamic_frame2, connection_type="documentdb",
                                             connection_options=write_documentdb_options)

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by downgrading Glue version from 3.0 to 2.0.
In 3.0 there is no way to set retryWrite setting while using dynamic frame.

A ticket has been created in their board and it was not resolved yet.
Issue in AWS board for reference - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/111       [An error occurred while calling o365.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Command failed with error 301: 'Retryable writes are not supported' on server ****.*****.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017.]

Comment: Add a quote or small example from the Github issue that way if the link becomes unavailable your answer will still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The correct option is retryWrites=false and needs to be at the end of the uri.

In your case: `documentdb_write_uri = "mongodb://<host name>:27017/?retryWrites=false"`

Comment: Got the error when used retryWrites at the end of URI -> An error occurred while calling o86.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=<clusterName>:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers `retryWrites=false` and needs to be at the end of the uri. However, doing so interferes with how other parameters to the uri are handled, specifically the database name, and the ssl configuration. As a result, these will also need to be added as parameters to the uri and removed from the write options, as so:

```
documentdb_uri = "mongodb://<host name>:27017"
documentdb_write_uri = "mongodb://<host name>:27017/test?retryWrites=false&ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true"

read_docdb_options = {
    "uri": documentdb_uri,
    "database": "test",
    "collection": "profiles",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "ssl": "true",
    "ssl.domain_match": "false"
}

write_documentdb_options = {
    "uri": documentdb_write_uri,
    "collection": "collection1",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>"
}

# Get DynamicFrame from DocumentDB
dynamic_frame2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="documentdb",
                                                               connection_options=read_docdb_options)

# Write DynamicFrame to DocumentDB
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(dynamic_frame2, connection_type="documentdb",
                                             connection_options=write_documentdb_options)

job.commit()
```

In orderfor the code snippet to work I would also expect partitioner options to be required as part of the write options, though that may be straying outside the scope of the initial question e.g.

```
write_documentdb_options = {
    "uri": documentdb_write_uri,
    "collection": "collection1",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>"
    "partitioner": "com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.SinglePartitionPartitioner",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB": "10",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionKey": "_id",
}
```